# Jira - Issues Filters Confluence Document

Tags: jira

I am trying to figure out if a query that list all Jira Issues that **Linked** with a Confluence Page is possible.

I know there are way to work around it, such as using labels, just really curious if something similar `linkedIssue` available for linked Confluence document.

Comment: @Jimi Wikman - I just think of this when I want to figure out all how to show all the issues linked to a document from Confluence in a confluence document just so someone who not very actively work on Jira can look at the Confluence (current act as our wiki platform) and knowing how things progress, what already done, oustanding, and maybe then he/she can identify what need to add more into the document, create more issues etc..

Answer (score 0):

https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.6.7/jira/jql-functions.html#_remote_issue_links
ScriptRunner plugin in Jira may do it

Comment: Have you used it before? And how it workout for you?